# What's the use of android App with no Components?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-10.0

I was searching for difference between Android 9 and 10 and happened to read this part of documentation

> Updated features
>
> Android Q Beta 2 contains the following updates to features released
> in previous versions of the beta program. Launcher icon visibility
>
> In Android Q Beta 2, packages that don't declare any permissions in
> their respective manifest files are hidden from the All apps tray, as
> are the following types of apps:
>
> - System apps
> - Apps that don't contain any components inside their
>   respective manifest's  tag

(https://web.archive.org/web/20190829024136/https://developer.android.com/preview/release-notes#launcher-icon-visibility-beta2)

So I get why an app with no permission can sometime be usefull, and also of course what's the point of System App.

However what's the idea behind treating differently app with no component? If an app has no component (no service, no activity ...), the app can't be launched and is useless right?

Comment: > `and also of course what's the point of System App`
"System app" refers to the apps that ship with the OS and contribute to it's functionality.

Comment: Note that apps without a launcher activity were always hidden from the apps tray. They are not useless, they might receive a few broadcasts or run a service to provide some functionality.

Comment: @Qunata Sure you don't need an Activity for your app to be usefull. But an app with no component can't declare Service nor receiver